# How to iterate through the same line of python code but with different variables and attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

as you can see i am writing the same code over and over again, how can i make an algorithm so to say, to iterate just a list of the parameters through the same line of code. Is that possible in this scenario or not.
What i am doing is i am programming some values into a device through a serial connection. I want to automate it so yeah. This code works perfectly fine but i want to know how to write an algorithm to iterate through only the parameters.
as yo can see only the .encode() value and the ft value is different in every line
An example would be very helpful.

```
def write_par(self):    
        try:
            reset_input = self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
            reset_input
    
            self.ser.write('\r\nft_seton ordoxo '.encode() + self.artikel_va.encode() + '\r\n'.encode())
            reset_input
            time.sleep(1.0)
                        
            self.ser.write('ft_seton hrdver '.encode() + self.HVVV.encode() + '\r\n'.encode())
            reset_input
            time.sleep(1.0)
            
            self.ser.write('ft_seton hrdbrd '.encode() + self.HWB.encode() + '\r\n'.encode())
            reset_input
            time.sleep(1.0)
        
            self.ser.write('ft_seton srll '.encode() + self.serien_nummer.encode() + '\r\n'.encode())
            reset_input
            time.sleep(1.0)
        
            self.ser.write('ft_seton addr '.encode() + self.mac.encode() + '\r\n'.encode())
            reset_input
            time.sleep(1.0)
        

    
        except Exception:
            print('Device parameters were not written')
            pass
```

Comment: Refactor the lines into a method with an argument

Comment: You have to work out what changes and what stays the same. Write a function which contains the bits that stay the same, but pass in parameters of the bits which change.

Comment: Sorry but i am not sure how to do that exactly

Comment: (btw where you have lines: `reset_input` - this does nothing and should be removed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the Python `for` functionality - it will always work as a "for each" and give you each element in a series.

You can either organize the names and attributes as tuples, or use the `zip` call:

```
def write_par(self):    
        try:
            reset_input = self.ser.reset_input_buffer  # <- NB. no () in this line, otherwise it is called a single time
            self.ser.write("\r\n")
    
            for name, value in [
                ("ortodoxo", self.artikel_va),
                ("hrdver", self.HVVV),
                ("hrdbrd", self.HWB),
                ("srll", self.serien_nummer),
                ("addr", self.mac),
            ]:
    
                self.ser.write(f'nft_seton {name} {value)\r\n'.encode()
                reset_input()
                time.sleep(1.0)
                       
    
        except Exception as error:
            print(f'Device parameters were not written: at {name} we got {error}')
            pass
```

As you can see, also: Python is not Basic, and there is no need to concatenate strings by opening and closing quotations and using the + operator. The "f-string" syntax will serve you well.

Another good practice is to print out *what* went wrong: you have that information while the program is running, and it is basically free to print it. If you print just "could not do it", that just means headaches that could have been avoided downstream.

Also, the first string to be printed out is different in your code: "nft_seto" vs "nt_seton" in your code. I assumed that was a typo. Otherwise, if you really need then to be different, just include this first string in the tuples, in the for loop and add another variable to carry it.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function to handle this like so

```
def write_encoded_values(str_a, str_b):
    self.ser.write(f'{str_a}{str_b}\r\n'.encode())
```

then you can call it like this for example

```
self.write_encoded_values('\r\nft_seton ordoxo ', self.artikel_va)
```

Comment: Thank you sir this was very helpful and quite simple

Comment: There are better ways to simply concatenate strings. Besides, the `.encode` method could have been called a single time.

Comment: @jsbueno good point - edited

Answer (score 1):

As others commented, put the statements to be executed repeatedly into a separate function. Something like this:

```
def write_something(self, name, value):
    self.ser.write(name.encode() + value.encode() + '\r\n'.encode())
    self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
    time.sleep(1.0)

def write_par(self):    
    try:
        write_something('\r\nft_seton ordoxo ', self.artikel_va)
        write_something('ft_seton hrdver ', self.HVVV)
        ...
    except Exception:
        print('Device parameters were not written')
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the sleep() calls (not sure why they're there) and also the NOOPs.

Build a control structure and iterate over it like this:

```
def write_par(self):
    CONTROL = {
        '\r\nft_seton ordoxo': 'artikel_va',
        'ft_seton hrdver': 'HVVV',
        'ft_seton hrdbrd': 'HWB',
        'ft_seton srll': 'serien_nummer',
        'ft_seton addr': 'mac'
    }

    try:
        self.ser.reset_input_buffer()

        for k, v in CONTROL.items():
            self.ser.write(f'{k} {getattr(self, v)}\r\n'.encode())

    except Exception:
        print('Device parameters were not written')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to remove repetition from code there are two general approaches:

1. **Create a helper function**

   In this method we create a function which we call multiple times

   This makes our code cleaner and easier to understand

   If we wanted to apply this to your code

   ```
   def write_par(self):    
        try:
            reset_input = self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
            reset_input

            self.write_ser('\r\nft_seton ordoxo ', self.artikel_va.encode())
            self.write_ser('ft_seton hrdver ', self.HVVV.encode())
            self.write_ser('ft_seton hrdbrd ', self.HWB.encode())
            self.write_ser('ft_seton addr ', self.mac.encode())

        except Exception:
            print('Device parameters were not written')
            pass
   ### Helper Methods ###
   def write_ser(self, text, frmt):
       """ 
       Writes a piece of text in encoded format 

       Inputs
           :text: <str> to be written, i.e '\r\nft_seton ordoxo '
           :frmt: <obj> to use for encoding, i.e self.artikel_va.encode()
       """
       # TODO: think about how you would implement this 
       # (hint: you already have)
       pass
   ```
2. **Use a loop**

   With a loop we are able to reduce the number of times we repeat a piece of code

   This is done by storing the different parts in each line inside some variable, usually a list, and iterating through it.

   At every iteration you will perform what is shared by each of the lines.

   If we wanted to apply this to your code

   ```
   def write_par(self):    
        try:
            reset_input = self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
            reset_input

            inputs = [
              ('\r\nft_seton ordoxo ', self.artikel_va.encode()),
              ('ft_seton hrdver ', self.HVVV.encode()),
              ('ft_seton hrdbrd ', self.HWB.encode()),
              ('ft_seton hrdbrd ', self.HWB.encode()),
              ('ft_seton addr ', self.mac.encode())
            ]

            for text, frmt in inputs:
               # TODO: Again you think about how you would implement this 

        except Exception:
            print('Device parameters were not written')
            pass
   ```

Which approach you should take will depend on what your code does, in your case either option would work, even a mix of both approaches would work!